# How to add row count when using filter view in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with a master list of dictionary words, and their language. I then create filter views for each language. Here is the Sanskrit filter view:

[image]

First off, notice the row numbers are the row numbers from the master list, so I can't easily tell how many rows there are for Sanskrit.

So how can I show the total count? Ideally I would show the total count perhaps in the header, or maybe just above the header in a stats column spanning all 6 columns, or maybe it just shows the virtual row number along the actual master list row number. Any of these solutions would be fine. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Given the layout of the table in the image, try the following in G1:

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,A2:A)
```

SUBTOTAL can perform various aggregations on vertical ranges, but it ignores all rows that have been filtered out; the '3' is telling it to do a 'COUNTA' (i.e. count all values) on the range.